# Is there an error in Steen and Seebach's Counterexamples space 99 "Maximal Compact Topology"?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In [Counterexamples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) space 99, the [Maximal Compact Topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000097) is asserted to be non-Hausdroff (note 1), KC (compacts are closed, note 3), and first-countable (note 5).

But [KC spaces are US](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369459/if-every-convergent-sequence-has-a-unique-limit-point-in-space-x-then-is-x/1369643#1369643), and [first countable US spaces are Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613212/one-point-compactification-of-the-rationals-is-not-second-countable/613474#613474). So where is the error?

Comment: The page you've linked claims that note 5 of Counterexamples in Topology states that space 99 is NOT first-countable. Can you check?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - the link is correct, but the book actually says the space is first-countable. I'll add a screenshot to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite this claim from the text:

[image: X is second countable since it is first countable and countable.]

the space is not first-countable. Any set containing $x$ and containing all but finitely-many points from each row of $\omega^2$ is open. So given a countable collection $U_n$ of neighborhoods of $x$, let's construct an open set that contains none of these.

For each $n<\omega$ choose $m_n<\omega$ with $(m_n,n)\in U_n$ (which must exist, as $U_n$ contains all but finitely-many points on the $n$th row). Then we may consider $$U=\{x\}\cup\{(m,n):n<\omega,m\geq m_n+1\}$$
noting that $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ but does not contain
$(m_n,n)\in U_n$ for each $n<\omega$.

EDIT: It seems this error depends on your edition of *Counterexamples*. Here is what I find in the copy via Google Books:

[image: X is not first countable since it is first countable and countable.]

However this also has a slight error: $y$ does in fact have a local countable basis; only $x$ is a point without a countable basis.